# D3 Simple Line Chart: Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a basic line chart using a 1 dimensional array containing numeric elements.

**chart.html**

```
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

**graph.js**

```
lineData = [10,15,20,25,30,35,40,35,30,25,20,15,10];
let svg = D3.select("#svg").attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

let chart = svg.append('g').classed('display', true).attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.padding.l + ', ' + this.padding.t + ')');

let x = D3.scaleLinear().domain([0, lineData.length]).range([0,width]);
let y = D3.scaleLinear().domain([0, D3.max(lineData)]).range([height, 0]);

let line = D3.line().x((d,i) => {return x(i);}).y((d) => {return y(d);}).curve();

chart.selectAll('.line').data([lineData]).enter().append('path').classed('line', true).attr('stroke', 'red').attr('d', (d) => {return line(d);});
```

and I keep getting this error: `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "[object Object]".`

**----------UPDATE (Un-simplified Angular Component)----------**

**bar-curve-chart.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import * as D3 from "d3";
import * as D3Tooltip from "d3-tip"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-curve-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-curve-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-curve-chart.component.css']
})
export class BarCurveChartComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('svg') svg:any;

  private chart:any;
  private padding = {t:50, r:75, b:25, l:20};
  private x:any;
  private y:any;

  // Change Any to Data Type
  @Input('data') data:number[] = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,30,25,20,15,10,5];
  @Input('lineData') lineData:any = [10,15,20,25,30,35,40,35,30,25,20,15,10];
  @Input('height') height:number = 700;
  @Input('width') width:number = 700;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.prep();
    this._plot();
  }

  private prep():void {
    let svg = D3.select(this.svg.nativeElement)
      .attr('width', this.width)
      .attr('height', this.height);

    this.chart = svg.append('g')
      .classed('display', true)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.padding.l + ', ' + this.padding.t + ')');

    this.x = D3.scaleLinear().domain([0, this.data.length]).range([0, this.width]);
    this.y = D3.scaleLinear().domain([0, D3.max(this.data)]).range([this.height, 0]);
  }

  private _plot():void {

    let line = D3.line()
      .x((d,i) => {return this.x(i);})
      .y((d) => {return this.y(d);}).curve();

    console.log(line(this.lineData));

    this.chart.selectAll('.line')
      .data([this.lineData])
      .enter()
        .append('path')
        .classed('line', true)
        .attr('stroke', 'red')
        .attr('d', (d) => {return line(d);});
  }

}
```

**bar-curve-chart.component.html**

```
<svg #svg ></svg>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't throw any error: https://jsfiddle.net/w6y91wek/ It's possible that, trying to simplify it, you eliminated the problem. Is that your real code? Please, share the code that actually causes an error.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado sorry for the late response. It was like 2am when I asked this question. I've updated the answer, the real thing is an angular component using D3.

Comment: In that case I suggest you add the Angular tag to your question, because the D3 code has no problem.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I know I'm probably missing something exceptionally retarded. And I've added the TS Tag also, just in case, but I do see this error popup on google for D3 Related questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in your definition of the line generator:

```
let line = D3.line()
  .x((d,i) => {return this.x(i);})
  .y((d) => {return this.y(d);}).curve();
```

If you use [`.curve()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#line_curve) without an argument, it acts as a getter:

> If *curve* is not specified, returns the current curve factory, which defaults to [curveLinear](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveLinear).

Therefore, `line` is going to hold a reference to the curve factory instead of the line generator. If you want a [curve factory](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curves) other than the default [d3.curveLinear](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveLinear), you need to pass it as a parameter, or you need to omit the call to `.curve()` to get the line generator instead.

---

As an aside: the above statement can be simplified/beautified to:

```
let line = D3.line()
  .x((d, i) => this.x(i))
  .y(this.y);
```

Comment: That's it. When I created the fiddle with OPs code I removed the method because there was no curve and, later, I forgot to test with it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did not have same problem as OP, but I had same error message as OP. The OP was not passing an argument to `curve(...)`, but I was not calling *`d3.line` as I should*!

I was only calling `d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5)`:

```
path.attr('d', d3.curveCatmullRomClosed.alpha(0.5))
```

Once I called d3.line().curve(...), as described [in the documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveCatmullRom_alpha), it worked:

```
path.attr('d', d3.line().curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5));
```